# Bit Buffer in C++

Tags: c++, fstream, bit

I'm doing an assignment in which I need to write bit to a buffer and once the buffer has been fill with 8 bits, I would flush. (Huffman compression)

I have a problem assigning/saving the intermediate stages during input. So I did a little test such as

```
char buf = 0;

cout << (buf | (1 << 1));
buf = (buf | (1 << 1));
cout << buf;
```

but not understand why I can't save the intermediate stage. The output of that would be:

```
2"happy face"
```

instead of

```
22
```

Can you please teach me how to save the intermediate stages?

Basically, I would need to write bit by bit to the buffer, and once the buffer is a byte, I will flush it to my output file.

Comment: When bitfiddling, you should try to use unsigned types, it makes things a lot easier in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is a bit tricky - it has to do with the type of the expression that you are writing out to `cout`, not with the value that you get as the result of the bitwise expression.

In the first case, the expression is `(buf | (1 << 1))`. According to the rules of C++, this expression has the type of `int`: the left side of the `OR` is expanded to match the right side.

In the second case, the type of the expression is `char`, because the operation has completed, and the result has been converted back to `char`.

That's why the first value is interpreted like a number, while the second one is interpreted like an ASCII character code of 2 that corresponds to ☺ when printed on your system. Adding a cast should fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

To set a particular bit you can use this code:

```
buf |= 1 << n; // where n is bit number from 0 to 7
```

To see what is in the `buf` convert it to int, otherwise you will see character:

```
std::cout << int( buf );
```

Or convert it into binary string by a function.